# Exception in execute jar

Tags: java, jar

```
java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for com/.../classfilename.class
```

I just changed one class in jar using winrar

Comment: 'i just changed one class in jar using winrar' => that's maybe the explanation ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jar` you modified was signed. Now your modification was detected by the system which doesn't allow execution of modified, signed `jar` files.

There's a reason that the `jar` was signed in the first place ...

Answer (score 0):

You should try to unzip your jar, Put your new class file and sign jar again with the required certificate.